# Какие есть способы хеширования данных в android?

Tags: java, android, хеширование

Мне необходимо обеспечить защиту своего приложения от копирования. Наткнулся на защиту самим сервисом google play, там, чтобы каждый раз не производить проверку, данные хешируются в обычный XML, а для меня это большая лажа, т.к. этот файлик легко достаётся и просматривается специальными программами и забить лицензию в пиратские копии не составляет труда.

Далее я придумал свой способ защиты, но данные также хранились в XML, но зашифрованны специальным способом и для каждого мобильника не подошли бы. Я уже было начал радоваться, что придумал что-то нормальное, и оно работало, когда я через программу расшарил своё приложение, оно действительно не запускалось на других телефонах, но была одна беда. Если я делал бэкап приложения, то данный фал успешно удалялся и прога успешно запускалась на других телефонах. Отсюда у меня и появилась нужда использовать какой-нибудь файл для хеширования (может, в папке assets или папке raw), главное, чтобы при бэкапе файлы не удалялись. Также стал задумываться об использовании 2-х этих методов, но сначала хотел бы услышать мнение знающих людей.

Comment: Хеширования или шифрования?

Answer (score 1):

Если действительно нужно защитить приложение от злоумышленников, то можно использовать, например, [dexprotector](https://dexprotector.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите вот это:

1. https://www.eldos.com/sbb/java-xml.php

Или же как вариант, в JAVA использовать AES, а в XML файле хранить что то в шифрованном виде, а уже сама JAVA пускай расшифровывает

Также можно использовать XSS4J (XML Security Suite for Java) от IBM или XMLCipher

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность ).